# adding a web app project to my solution, and the other projects in the solution already use .net framework, can I use .net core for the new project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Ive build out a service as a console application, it exists across 2 different projects in the solution, both are in .NET framework. I am wanting to add in an api level to this and am wondering if I should continue to use .NET framework for the web application project, or if I can use .NET Core without messing anything up.

Comment: It's probably more trouble than it's worth compared against just upgrading your existing projects to .NET6.  Though depending on what dependencies you have, that can end up being tricky as well.

Comment: @KirkWoll so unfortunately some of the dependencies im using in the other projects are making me stay in .net 4.7. If I cant migrate to .net 6, you think I should just make the new project under the same version (framework 4.7)?

Comment: unfortunately that will probably be the easiest solution for you.  Kind of a bummer, obviously.  Are your dependencies nuget packages?  Do you have an example of one that required .net 4.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the APIs you use in your application. If you only use APIs included in `.NET Standard` then no problem to use them in an application under `.NET 6`. Otherwise I join Kirk Woll to migrate your code under `.NET 6` especially since the unification of the platform. I think it will remain only `.NET 6` aka `.NET core` in the future.

Comment: so unfortunately some of the dependencies im using in the other projects are making me stay in .net 4.7. If I cant migrate to .net 6, you think I should just make the new project under the same version (framework 4.7)?

Comment: Yes you can continue with this framework. On the other hand if this project is intended to be maintained for a while I advise you to migrate to .net 6 because .net framework will be doomed to disappear since the unification with .net core (.net 6).